# Deserializing Aggregate Root ID in MongoDB

Tags: c#, json, mongodb

I'm trying to implement a repository layer for my Aggregate Roots in MongoDB.  I'm having trouble fully deserializing my entities when I am retrieving them from the store.  Generally speaking, these entities do not have a default constructor and use a GUID as their entity ID.  The ID field is `Id`

```
// Example Aggregate Root
public class MyAggregateRoot : Entity<Guid> {

    // New Constructor
    public MyAggregateRoot(string someInitialState) 
        : base(Guid.NewGuid()) { }

    // Reinitializing Constructor
    public MyAggregateRoot(Guid id, string someInitialState) 
        : base(id) { }

}

public abstract class Entity<T> {

    protected Entity(T id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public T Id { get; }

}
```

I am retrieving the entity like this:

```
public MyAggregateRoot GetById(Guid id) {

    var collections = _db.GetCollection<Account>("accounts");
    var entity = collections.Find(a => a.Id == id).ToList().FirstOrDefault();

    return entity;

}
```

The problem I have is that upon retrieving the entity, everything seems like it deserializes properly except for the `Id` field, which comes out to be a default value of `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`.

When I look up the record in the console, I can see that the `Id` field is not directly serialized, and instead is serialized as `_id`.

```
{ "_id" : BinData(3,"jac2kSM6aU2xXnS0DXNkJA=="), "SomeInitialState" : "My Incredibly Significant Value" }
```

I know Mongo is able to associate the correct ID to `Id` because of the following lambda:

`collections.Find(a => a.Id == id).ToList()`

But it just doesn't seem to connect the final dots when deserialzing.  Is there any way to achieve what I am after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the Mongo serializer cannot handle properties that have a `private readonly` setter.  When deserializing an object, is just resorts to using the default value for these fields

Once I changed the `Id` property on `Entity<T>` to use a `private` setter, the value was properly serialized.

```
public abstract class Entity<T> {

    protected Entity(T id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public T Id { get; private set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

While your own answer is correct that Mongo cannot handle the readonly property, the underlying cause is a little different.

`get` only properties don't have a setter *at all*. Instead, the following

```
public T Id { get; }
protected Entity(T id) { Id = id; }
```

Is equivalent to the following pre-C# 6 code

```
private readonly T _id;
public T Id { get { return _id; } }
protected Entity(T id) { _id = id; }
```

Wherein the compiler automagically replaced the reference to the property with one to the field in the constructor

So the problem is that the MongoDB can't find *any* setter for the property, because there isn't one.